# Ordered Set based on linked list

Tags: java, sortedset

I am working with java, and I need to implement an ordered set, base on a linked list using the interface SortedSet. How do I implement the methods from SortedSet by this conditions?

Answer (score 1):

Since this is clearly homework (or a similar learning exercise) it is inappropriate to give you code.  So here are some **Hints** to get you started.

1. You need to keep the elements of the linked list ordered at all times
2. If the linked list is a wrapped `LinkedList`, you can delegate a lot of the `SortedSet` methods to the list.
3. Alternatively, consider using `AbstractSet` as the base class for your set.

(You will need to check the wording of your homework's requirement to figure out if you are *allowed* to use `LinkedList` or `AbstractList`.)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you need to use Set feature to delete duplicates from your LinkedList, and to use SortedSet to keep it sorted.

So, the easiest way to do that, if you have a linked list, is to do something like this. For this example I've used LinkedList which would be filled with random numbers:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args){
    //Declare the LinkedList of Integers
    LinkedList<Integer> linkedList = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    //use special method to fill List with 10 numbers which are less than 100
    linkedListRandomFill(linkedList, 10, 100);

    //After you pass the LinkedList to the following constructor
    //  the list is sorted automatically
    SortedSet<Integer> sortedSet = new TreeSet<Integer>(linkedList);

    //After that you can recreate your linked list,
    //  just pass the SortedSet to LinkedList constructor
    linkedList = new LinkedList<Integer>(sortedSet);
    System.out.println(linkedList);
}

public static void linkedListRandomFill(
        LinkedList<Integer> linkedList,
        int size,
        int limit){
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        linkedList.add(rnd.nextInt(limit));
    }
}
```

Also we could refactor that:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        LinkedList<Integer> linkedList = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        linkedListRandomFill(linkedList, 10, 100);
        linkedList = getSortedListOfUniqueValues(linkedList);
        System.out.println(linkedList);
    }

    public static void linkedListRandomFill(
            LinkedList<Integer> linkedList,
            int size,
            int limit){
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            linkedList.add(rnd.nextInt(limit));
        }
    }

    public static LinkedList<Integer> getSortedListOfUniqueValues(LinkedList<Integer> list){
        SortedSet<Integer> sortedSet = new TreeSet<Integer>(list);
        return new LinkedList<Integer>(sortedSet);
    }
}
```